# sql query to print ID:Name mapping

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mariadb

Is it possible to use only sql query no procedural language to get below format output

```
ID   Name
-------------
1     a,b,c
2     x,y,z
3     m,n,l
```

I want this to print like below

```
1:a
1:b
1:c
2:x
2:y
2:z
```

Is this is possible with only my sql query or I have to use UDF ?

Comment: why `mysql` and `sql-server`?

Comment: Saving data as csv is very bad db design

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can-

The solution below is for `Mysql`.

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to reverse the process of 'group_concat'.

Here is your sql-

```
SELECT
  id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(names, ',', n.d+1), ',', -1) name
FROM
  users
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 d UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(names, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(names)-n.d
ORDER BY
  id,
  n.d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE(ID,Name)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'a,b,c' union all
SELECT 2,'x,y,z' union all
SELECT 3,'m,n,l' 
)

  SELECT ID,   Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data  
        FROM  
        (
            SELECT  ID, 
                 CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Name, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
                 from CTE

        ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

---

If you want ouput with ':' separter ,below is the code

```
;WITH CTE(ID,Name)
AS
(
SELECT 1,'a,b,c' union all
SELECT 2,'x,y,z' union all
SELECT 3,'m,n,l' 
)
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)),' : ', CAST(Data AS VARCHAR(5))) As [OutPut] From
(
  SELECT ID,   Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Data  
        FROM  
        (
            SELECT  ID, 
                 CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Name, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data  
                 from CTE

        ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
        )Final
```

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL server`, you could do it by a query with `CROSS APPLY` and `xml query`

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE (ID int IDENTITY (1,1), Name varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @SampleData (Name)
VALUES ('a,b,c'), ('x,y,z'), ('m,n,l')

;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT *,
         CAST('<x>' + replace(sd.Name, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS xml) AS xmlText
   FROM @SampleData sd
)
SELECT CONCAT(t.ID, ':',v.x.value('.','varchar(50)')) AS Result
FROM temp t
CROSS APPLY 
t.xmlText.nodes('/x') AS v(x)
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/IHQF16100